# $N$ doors Monty hall type problem

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem, monty-hall

In Peter office there are $N$ doors. Behind each door except
one hides a doll. Lucy know what is behind each door while Peter does not. Peter has to select a door and wins if there is no doll behind it. Peter selects a door, instead of opening that door, Lucy opens $k$ other doors behind each of which is a doll , with $1\le k\le N-2$.
Now Peter is given a choice to switch the door.

1. What is the probability for Peter to win if Peter does not switch
   his initial choice?
2. probability if he switch his initial choice
3. prove that whatever are values of $N$ and $k$ , Peter should always
   switch doors.

Comment: We will be able to help you better if you tell us what specifically you are confused about, what you have tried, where you are stuck, etc. This site does not react kindly to questions which just have the problem statement with no input on the poster.

Comment: I just need help with part 1. A beginning kind of thing how to approach it. That's all So I am assure how to proceed further.

Comment: If that is the case, you should only ask part 1.  Otherwise it's debatable whether an answer to only part 1 is complete or not.  But even if you fix that, this doesn't really address the concern Mike brought up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initial selection win probability is $\frac{1}{N}$.  What happens after that doesn't effect result of initial selection.  Win probability if he switches is then $\frac{N-1}{N}\times\frac{1}{(N-1-k)}$.

Comment: okay. So the answer to Q1 is $\frac{1}{N}$. and Q2 is $\frac{N-1}{N}\times\frac{1}{(N-1-k)}$ That seems a very simple argument. I was thinking this would be complex. Just confirming is these answers are correct. I do understand how you arrived there

Comment: Why does opening k other doors doesn't change the probability for Q1. As now the k doors have shown to be wookie so probability = 1/(N-k). Why can't it be thought along these lines

Comment: @bittu  The probability that the chosen door is a win is 1/N to start with.  Since the dolls don't move, this doesn't change.  The probability that the win is one of the other doors is (N-1)/N.  Opening all except one of the others leaves (N-1)/N as the probability for the remaining door.